# Django: How to add products to order model as whatever I try its showing ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'add' or filter or similar error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello I am trying to learn developing a ecommerce website, and in the order model, I have this product with manytomany relation with order item. so whenever an order is processed, I would like to add the products from order item model to this product object of order model. How to implement this?

Please have a look at the code.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField('OrderItem', related_name='ordered_products')
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

orderitem

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def processorder(request):
    transaction_id = create_transaction_id()
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    user = request.user
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=user, complete=False)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id
    order.items = items

    if total == order.get_cart_total:
        order.complete = True
    order.save()
    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
        user=user,
        order=order,
        address=data['shipping']['address'],
        city=data['shipping']['city'],
        state=data['shipping']['state'],
        zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
        )

    return JsonResponse('Payment Complete', safe=False)
```

How can I add the products ordered to the order model? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
for item in items:
    order.product.add(item)
```

and not `order.items = items`. The `.add` method is available on the many to many field as defined by you, in this case, it's `product` field of the `Order` model. Also, I'm not sure why you are doing `items = order.orderitem_set.all()`. `orderitem_set` will not be a valid attribute on `order` since the field name is different (`product`).

Comment: May I ask why do we need Order as foreign key in OrderItem? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it should be required, since we already have a relation with OrderItem defined in the Order model (via product).